# Advanced Multivariable Calculus question needed help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Problem 3: Suppose that k is a positive number. Suppose that K is a number collection such that for any number in K, there is another number in K, such that the difference between these two numbers is less than k. Must K have a limit point? Explain your answer using English sentences.

Answer (score 1):

No. For $k > 0$, let $0 < \epsilon < k$. Then, $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the given property, as any two adjacent elements in $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}$ differ by $\epsilon < k$, but $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}$ is discrete, so all points in $\epsilon\mathbb{Z}$ are isolated points.